# Standalone isolated NET6(7) Winforms application: is it possile?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, deployment, mfc

Colleagues, hello.
We have an existing desktop application in combination: MFC core app (.exe) and C# extensions (.dll). It works great: c++ code can execute c# code.
We use now Net Framework 4.6.1 and we want to update everything to last actual versions (net 7, vs 2022, etc). And we have done this already: the couple MFC C++ and NET7 works correctly.

But our main issue is that many of our clients can NOT update their servers, so we can NOT install NET7 there (but they have net 4.6 as a part of OS).

Only one idea now how to overcome this: create a standalone application somehow which will work WITHOUT NET7 installation.

Is it possible? I know that the Docker now is very popular for the deployment, but really not can we "pack" everything (framework, exe, dll files) into one exe file.
If somebody has similar experience, please, share it.
Thank you.

Comment: If you publish application like any software package clients can install like any software package with the setup.exe that is produced by publishing.

Comment: Unlike the .NET Framework, where there is one OS-wide version installed and no real option for _Side-by-side_ (aka _SxS_) versions being installed, .NET Core (+ .NET 5, 6, 7, ...) is not a component of the OS; you can install it as part of your app.

Comment: @jdweng, no setup and installation. the software may works from a shared driver or from centralized server like citrix. we can ask users just unzip some files into an existing folder.

Comment: @Flydog57, could you please expand your last thought? How can I do this practically? Docker? Something else?

Comment: @SergeyAlikin: As a test: Create a simple client-side app (console, winforms, ...) using .NET 6.  Compile it.  Run it.  Then create another using .NET 7.  Compile it and run it.  Now run them both at the same time.  They are both going to work because you have both the .NET 6 and .NET 7 SDKs installed (all this assumes you have done this).  When you _publish_ the apps, the publishing tool will package what the app needs in the application's package

Comment: @Flydog57 thanks for your explanation. I did this before and had everything in one folder. But I thought that this "package" will not work without installed NET. I will try your advice.

Comment: For Net 7 to run on a deploy machine the runtime version of Met 7 MUST be installed  or the full version of Net 7 must be installed.  Publishing the app installs the runtime version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can publish your .net 7 app as a self-contained executable.

Here's the link for [.NET application publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

Which states: "When publishing your app and creating an executable, you can publish the app as **self-contained** or framework-dependent. Publishing an app as self-contained **includes the .NET runtime with the app**, and users of the app don't have to worry about installing .NET before running the app."